# will_paginate find out if I'm on the last page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, will-paginate

I'm trying to use will paginate with ajax, but I don't show the `will_paginate` buttons... instead I use a `see more` button, that makes an Ajax request and append the results to the page.
what I'm trying to do is disable this `see more` button if I hit the last page of records!!
Any idea how to know that the current page is the last page??

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
@collection.total_pages == @collection.current_page
```

Comment: Is there a better API doc for will_paginate that can be used to find these methods? The one on Github falls kind of short.

Comment: You can also use `@collection.next_page` (or `@collection.next_page.present?`), which reads a bit nicer in my opinion.

Comment: For a list of collection methods, see: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/will_paginate/3.1.6/WillPaginate/CollectionMethods

Answer (score 2):

Accessing the `@collection.total_pages` method will give you the total number of pages currently being returned. You can use this to evaluate against your active page using the `@collection.current_page` method. This is still applicable if you're reloading your collection on each expansion.

The implementation will be to use the AJAX call to replace the HTML content if this evaluation is true.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `next_page` condition

```
@collection.next_page.present?
```